# Why the default argument behaved globally immutable?

Tags: python

The `default arguments` in Python are intuitively the variables locally scoped but globally mutable.

Below, why had the second call to `my_sum` the result `20` although I expected it `30` ?

```
def my_append(el, ar = []):
  ar.append(el)
  return ar
print my_append(10) # => [10]
print my_append(20) # => [10, 20]

def my_sum(i, sum = 0):
  sum += i
  return sum
print my_sum(10) # => 10
print my_sum(20) # => 20
```

Comment: Because integers are immutable.

Comment: Mutability doesn't depend on whether it's a keyword argument or not, but on the *data type*. Lists are mutable, integers aren't. With `sum += i` you aren't mutating any `int`, you're **re-assigning** `sum` to a new integer `(sum + 1)`.

Comment: Expanding on "blame the data type, not the scope" - other than syntax, the key difference between lists and tuples in Python is that lists are mutable, whereas tuples are immutables. Both are compound types that hold sequences of values. In a list, you can replace one of the values (a mutation of the list). In a tuple, you can't - if you want a new tuple that's mostly the same but with one element changed, you have to make a whole new replacement tuple.

Comment: In non-Python-specific terminology, immutable values are actual values with value semantics. Mutable values are containers that refer to elements by mutable reference, so the references can be changed to substitute different elements in. Immutable containers (like tuple) probably still hold references to the elements, but since the container is immutable, the references to elements can't be mutated. Variables always refer to objects (mutable or immutable) by mutable reference, hence Pythons pervasive reference semantics, and immutable structures  can always be replaced if you think big enough.

Comment: Actually, "hence Pythons pervasive reference semantics" was wrong. Pythons pervasive reference semantics are because many useful compound types are mutable. What I was trying to explain is that you can always replace an object at some point - if the object you want to mutate is immutable you replace the thing that contains it, or the thing that contains that, and so on - and once you reach the local/global variable level, the content of that can always be replaced - as with the simple case of those immutable integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help clarify this, consider this one-line change:

```
def my_append(el, ar=[]):
    ar = ar + [el]
    # ar.append(el)
    return ar

print(my_append(10))  # [10]
print(my_append(20))  # [20]
```

So the issue is not to do with mutability or immutability, but the fact that the second version rebinds the name.

This is a more subtle issue than the commentators are suggesting.  `int.__iadd__` doesn't exist, so in the case of integers that operation falls back to `sum = sum + i`, again rebinding the name.

However, `list.__iadd__` does exist, and it mutates the existing object.  This is why you see the changes to the default argument occur.

Comment: Are function parameters and local variables semantically distinguished in Python ? In this case, the param var has effectively been shadowed by the local var on the left of the assignment.

Comment: Inside the function body the function parameters and local variables are, for all practical purposes, the same thing.  So when you rebind the name, I suppose you could say it's shadowed the name pointing to the previous object, yes.  The original object in the argument spec is still accessible, both inside and outside the function, as the first item contained in `my_sum.func_defaults` (`my_sum.__defaults__` on python3).

Comment: In this case, they're not.